# Mouse Hover Highlight Customisation via CSS

Tags: html, css, confluence

The following is a TOC I have implemented on an instance of Confluence.

[image]

It's look has been customized so that when hovering over a menu item with the mouse, the corresponding menu item is highlighted as in the case of the **2. Navigation Bar** menu item in the above image.

The hover effect is achieved via the following CSS code:

```
.toc-link:hover {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I'd like for the hover effect to span the entire width of the box though, similar to the image below:

[image]

What property would I have to insert into my CSS code to achieve the desired effect?

Thank you.

Comment: Give that styling to the `<li>` element.

Comment: I think you are giving hover for `a` tag instead of give to its parent .

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by setting `display:block` on your `<a>` element. The hover styles should be on your anchor tag, not on your `<li>`, for example:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

If your list items do not have an anchor tag inside, you can achieve it like so:

```css
li {
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The display: block; property seems to have worked, almost!

The hover highlight extends all the way on the right, but on the left, it ends before the bullet points. Is there a way for it to highlight over the bullet all the way to the end of the box on the left as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```css
#content {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

li{
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #ABADBB;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Opening the Asset Browser
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li>1. Menu</li>
      <li>2. Navigation Bar</li>
      <li>3. Folder Tree</li>
      <li>4. Search Result Pane</li>
    </ul>
    <li>
      Live Updates for Asset Resources Selectors
    </li>
    <li>
      Texture Tool-tips
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```